# Mysql INsert appened var

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

I can't get my query to  insert one of my vars while it is being appened. if i hard set it, it  will insert.

```
   preg_match_all("/<\s*p[^>]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>/", $new_post, $matches);

$article = ' ';

foreach ($matches[0] as $media){
$article .= $media;

}

$query = "INSERT INTO blog_post (date,article,link) VALUES('$date','$article','$guid_clean')";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

Everything works, IE I can echo out the $article and if I hard set it and skip the foreach I can even insert $article. $date and $guid_clean work fine.

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to achieve with the `preg_match_all()`. Also, what does `mysql_error()` tell you when the query does not succeed? I'm betting on an errant quote in the article body, since you haven't used `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @Michael, thks... gonna delete the comment then. It doesn't do anybody any good to google by and read it. Thks.

Comment: @Michael, the `preg_match_all` looks like it's just extracting out the contents of a `<p>...</p>`.

Comment: @Michael I'm trying to insert an article. I have it matched readable in the $article. `mysql_error()` wont say anything. BUT `mysql_real_escape_string()` did it thank you so much.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Yes this is what I'm doing... or trying to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not escaped your input variables with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, and it is likely that an apostrophe or single-quote inside the article body is breaking and invalidating the SQL statement.

```
$article = mysql_real_escape_string($article);
// And if necessary if these came from user input...
$guid_clean = mysql_real_escape_string($guid_clean);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($date);

$query = "INSERT INTO blog_post (date,article,link) VALUES('$date','$article','$guid_clean')";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```